# Authenticate returns null always

Tags: python-3.x, django

when i authenticate it returns null and so i cant login even when i have username and password in my database

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login ,logout
from .models import Signups
from .forms import SignForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.

def loginpage(request):
    a=Signups.objects.all()
    form1 = AuthenticationForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form1 = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        print(username,password)
        user = authenticate(request,username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request,user)
            return redirect('signed', pk=user.pk)
        else:
            return HttpResponse("username or password is incorrect")

    return render(request, 'database/loginpage.html', {'form1': form1})

def frontpage(request):
    return render(request,'database/frontpage.html')
def signup(request):
    form=SignForm()
    if request.method=='POST':
        form = SignForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user=form.save()
            return redirect("signed",pk=user.pk)
    return render(request,'database/signup.html',{'form':form})
def signed(request,pk):
    sign=Signups.objects.get(id=pk)
    return render(request,'database/signed.html',{'sign':sign})
```

this is my views.py

i want to go to a page where it shows username and password and i have written the code for that and it works but the login form is not taking me there.

Edit: I fixed the problem. I was trying to get it to check the data from database and I didn't knew authenticate only worked for users and not the data in database.

Answer (score 0):

There is many possible things that could be causing this.

Make sure the form data is posting over first.

Then check your settings for configuration.

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "Your.UserModel"

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
   'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)
```

Also make sure you're not setting the the user `is_active` to false anywhere. You will not be able to log a user in if that is set to false.

Comment: AUTH_USER_MODEL is not working when i put it in settings.py it asks for a required field and when i enter a required field it shows error that there is a required field could you tell me how to use it

Comment: @whrecker can you show both errors as well as the POST data you're getting in your view